# Exibir conteúdo do atributo "title" ao lado do elemento option

Tags: javascript, dom, atributos, option

Possuo um conjunto de miniatura de imagens no `option` do `select`.

Gostaria que o *script* o introduzisse automaticamente a legenda, para cada uma dessas imagens no `select`, baseada no *atributo* `title` da *tag* `option`.

O exemplo do que tenho feito:

```js
window.onload = function(){
var opt = document.getElementById('lista').getElementsByTagName('option');

var txt = document.getElementById('lista').getElementsByTagName('b');

for (var n=0; n < txt.length; n++) {
  for (var i=0; i < opt.length; i++) {
    txt[n].getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = opt[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[0].title;
    }
  } 
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
}

option {
 font-size: 12pt;
 color: white;
 padding: 10 10 10 10;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 

 background-size: 100px;
 height: 50px;
}

option:hover { 
 background-color: whitesmoke; 
    border-right: 2px solid tomato;
 cursor: pointer; 
    size: 150%;
}

.bloc select {  
 width:450px; 
 height:100%;
 padding:30px; 
 background-color: white;
    float: right;
    border:none;
    margin: 0px -20px 0px 0px;
    }
    
.bloc {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
  <select id="lista" size="3">
 <option style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.jpg);" title="Big Buck Bunny">Big Buck Bunny</option>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b></b>

 <option style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.jpg);" title="Madagascar 2">Madagascar 2</option>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b></b>

 <option style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.jpg);" title="Procurando Dory">Procurando Dory</option>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b></b>
  </select>
<div>
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que, se utilizar o *atributo* `text` do `option` então ele ficará sobre a imagem - *então vi que seria necessário investir esforços em trabalhar com o atributo `title`, ja que o mesmo fica em oculto, bastaria apenas buscar uma maneira de pegar o seu conteúdo e por entre uma outra tag texto*. Como exemplo: `span`, `b`, `p`, `strong`, `small` etc...

O *script*, **apesar de o console não acusar erro algum**, ainda não me trouxe nenhum resultado.

Comment: Imagino que vc poderia usar uma lista LI para fazer isso em vez de SELECT, até porque o SELECT não é bem a melhor escolha para fazer tal coisa. Também vc não pode colocar elementos entre as OPTION pq o HTML não vai exibir.

Comment: Sim, seria uma opção. Faz o SELECT  na largura das imagens e coloca uma lista ao lado exibindo os nomes.

Comment: @dvd Então, como eu ja consegui capturar o `title` e jogar dentro da `div` vou preparar uma resposta pra este tópico. Ficará pra futuras pesquisa e consulta.

Comment: Eu havia pensado nisso tb, mas não sabia que o OPTION poderia ter pseudo-elementos :D... mas veja que se o título do filme for longo, o texto some pela direita ;/

Comment: Eu vi, mas clicando no <p> não seleciona a option.

Comment: @dvd É um detalhe que vou editar, pois ainda estou moldado uma explicação coerente ao contexto, e deixar uma dica para `loop` criar os elemento `p` dinâmicamente uma vez que não se sabe a quantidade de ítem que possa vim a adicionar no `select`, não ter a necessidade de ficar inserindo _tags_ `p` manualmente no `container`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que não é necessario o javascript neste caso.

> tambem seria possivel usar **Javascript** mas acho mais simples não usa-lo neste momento.

**Solução**

Usar uma pseudo classe no css, neste caso o `::after` para abrigar o texto e poder movimenta-lo, assim você pode usar o `tranform:` junto ao `translate` para movimenta-lo em relação a si mesmo. Por fim para pegar o atributo title da tag, usamos a função `attr()` do css, que recebe o attributo que você deseja pegar o conteudo.

Espero ter ajudado **;D**

```css
body {
   background-color: whitesmoke;
}

option {
   font-size: 12pt;
   color: white;
   padding: 10 10 10 10;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 

   background-size: 100px;
   height: 50px;
}

option:hover { 
   background-color: whitesmoke; 
   border-right: 2px solid tomato;
   cursor: pointer; 
   size: 150%;
}

option::after {
   content: attr(title);
   display: block;
   color: black;
   transform: translateX(110px);
}

.bloc select {  
   width:450px; 
   height:100%;
   padding:30px; 
   background-color: white;
   float: right;
   border:none;
   margin: 0px -20px 0px 0px;
}

.bloc {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
  <select id="lista" size="3">
 <option title="Big Buck Bunny" style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.jpg);"></option>

 <option title="Madagascar 2" style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.jpg);"></option>

 <option title="Procurando Dory" style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.jpg);"></option>
  </select>
<div>
```

Comment: Tai uma coisa que não sabia. Parabéns cara! Mesmo assim, irei colocar uma solução _javascript_.

Answer (score 1):

Segue problema solucionado em Javascript em conjunto com CSS:

```js
var opt = document.getElementById('lista');

var txt = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('p');

  for (var i=0; i < opt.length; i++) {
    txt[i].innerHTML = opt[i].title;
    }
```

```css
body {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
}

option {
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-size: 100px 45px;
 height: 50px;
    color: white;
}

option:hover { 
 background-color: whitesmoke; 
    border-right: 2px solid tomato;
 cursor: pointer; 
    }

        .bloc select {
            width:280px;
            border: none;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px -176px 0px 0px;
            background-color: white;
      color: white;

        }

        .bloc {
            vertical-align: top;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
#container  {
    width: 265px;
    color: black; 
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div class="bloc">
  <select id="lista" size="3">
 <option style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.jpg);" title="Big Buck Bunny"></option>

 <option style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.jpg);" title="Madagascar 2"></option>

 <option style="background-image: url(https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.jpg);" title="Procurando Dory"></option>
  </select>
  <div>
  
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Legal, o unico ponto seria adicionar o hover a tag **p** tambem para não perder o efeito